# '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this generic function:

```
  ValueType get<ValueType>(String keyToRead) {
    try {
      return _dataClient.get(keyToRead) as ValueType;
    } on SocketException catch (error) {...
```

And I call it like this:

```
  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> getUserRegistration() {
    return dataClient.get<Map<String, dynamic>>(UserRegistrationFieldKeys.self);
  }
```

but since I changed from using a [get_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage) box for my _dataClient to a [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) box, I'm getting this error:

```
The following ProviderException was thrown building LoggedOutPageView(dirty, dependencies: [UncontrolledProviderScope], state: _ConsumerState#6c90b):
An exception was thrown while building AutoDisposeProvider<RegisterViewModel>#00006().

Thrown exception:
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Stack trace:
#0      LocalDataClient.get
package:vepo/…/data_clients/local_data_client.dart:51
#1      UserRegistrationLocalDataSource.getUserRegistration
package:vepo/…/user_registration/user_registration_local_data_source.dart:22
#2      UserRegistrationRepository.getUserRegistration
package:vepo/…/user-registration/user_registration_repository.dart:31
```

Hive must store the data as a different format, possible due to encrypting, but how can I account for that and get rid of this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```dart
Map<String, dynamic>.from(dataClient.get(UserRegistrationFieldKeys.self))`;
```

And you can remove the generic function as well if you use this.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `_dataClient.get(keyToRead)` function returns an `_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>` datatype. When you assign a type `Map<String, dynamic>` to the output of the function like this: `dataClient.get<Map<String, dynamic>>()`, it means you are expecting the output of the function to be Map while it's not, thus causing error.

In this case, you should do the typecasting **after** getting the output of that function, something like:

```dart
 @override
  Map<String, dynamic> getUserRegistration() {
    return Map<String, dynamic>.from(dataClient.get(UserRegistrationFieldKeys.self));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = yourHiveBox.get("key").cast<String, dynamic>();
```